# How to restrict upload size of an object in AWS S3 bucket using presigned URLs?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I would like to share pre-signed URL with my clients to upload any object to my s3 bucket. I would like to add validations for the maximum size a user can upload using the presigned URL. Also, if possible, I want my users to upload a particular file type only? How can I implement that?

I am using AWS Java SDK. If not through SDK, can we create a bucket level policy that ensures a upload request fails if the object size increases a certain limit?

Comment: I use conditions but in java doesnt works i can do it with nodejs.

Comment: @JavierSolisGuzman can you please share nodejs code? I haven't worked in nodejs yet but would like to see how it works there.

Comment: yes,  this works for me https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-s3-post-signed-urls/ , sorry for the delay

Comment: it seems this is not supported in Java :(